# Z3Py Timeout parameter

Tags: z3py

Is the timeout parameter in the Z3 python API meant to be a strict upper bound for the execution time? Because if I set it to ten minutes it runs for a few minutes more than that.
The solver always terminates. That’s not the problem. It’s just that it always overshoots the timeout specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking at elapsed (i.e., wall-)time or CPU-time?

I believe z3's timeout mechanism uses `rlimit`: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/unix/versions/1.5.5/topics/rlimit

As noted in that page:

> RLIMIT_CPU : a limit in seconds on the amount of CPU time (not elapsed
> time) that the process may consume. When the process reaches the soft
> limit, it is sent a SIGXCPU signal.

So, elapsed time doesn't necessarily match CPU time, as there might be other processes that stop z3 from running.

Comment: I was looking at the elapsed time, but I was suspecting that the timeout might use CPU-time. I'll have a closer look at it. Thank you for the hint.